# Firebase "Error: Key creator was undefined. Cannot pass undefined in JSON. Use null instead."

Tags: json, angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I am using angularFire 0.8.2 for an app I am building. The app is based on thinkster.io's angular-firebase tutorial. The problem that I am facing is at the point where I have to create a custom user profile and and access the data stored in it. Especially, I am not able to make a post once I am logged in as a user.

I reviewed the error several times and kept getting the following error:

```
Error: Key creator was undefined. Cannot pass undefined in JSON. Use null instead.
```

The stack trace points to a service that was created to allow for post creations.

Here is the code:

```
var Post = {
    all: posts,
    create: function (post) {
      return posts.$add(post);
    },
    get: function (postId) {
      return $firebase(ref.child('posts').child(postId)).$asObject();
    },
    delete: function (post) {
      return posts.$remove(post);
    }
  };
```

I looked at solutions provided for this same problem but they were not very helpful. I am only guessing the problem has something to do with the $add() method above. Can anyone help?

Comment: As it states, you can't pass undefined into a JSON structure. You have an undefined value in your post. You can debug this a great deal faster and easier than we can and get to the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked over a year ago however I thought I'd still add some help. My resolution was rather simple so maybe it will help future folks.  The reason you see this message is because you have an undefined variable somewhere in your code/object you are attempting to $add.  Firebase will reject the entire $add object if there are any undefined variables in your object's properties.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This was the issue for me thanks! Just like to add for anyone who might be stumbling across this error `undefined` can also mean misspelled. So be sure to check that there are no typos in the object's keys, either in the view or the controller. Firebase will ignore any property that doesn't match exactly, which means it will be `undefined` making Firebase reject the entire operation.

Answer (score 0):

In short there is really no error. When you followed the tutorial, the initial ***account you created had no username field*** and hence you did not give any. Now the updated code needs one and there is none. Just try creating a new account and post a new link. You won't see that error.